# How to return json object with json array inside of it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, mariadb

i have many to many relationship
like this :
Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB

- table colors(id,name).
- table items(id,title....).
- table item_color(id,items_id,color_id).

my query is like this :

```
SELECT items.*,colors.name FROM items,item_color,colors
 where
 items.id = item_color.item_id
 and
 colors.id = item_color.color_id
```

i use php function `json_encode()`.
**how to return this** :

```
{
    "id": "22",
    "title": "my products 515151",
    "descreption": "5454545455",
    "price": "0.05",
    "quantity": "2",
    "date_added": "2021-01-29 14:37:24",
    "primary_image": "http://localhost/ecomerce/uploads/1611927444hat.jpg",
    "color": [
      0 : "pink",
      1 : "white"
      ]

  }
```

instead if this:

```
    "id": "22",
    "title": "my products 515151",
    "descreption": "5454545455",
    "price": "0.05",
    "quantity": "2",
    "date_added": "2021-01-29 14:37:24",
    "primary_image": "http://localhost/ecomerce/uploads/1611927444hat.jpg",
    "color": "pink"
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "title": "my products 515151",
    "descreption": "5454545455",
    "price": "0.05",
    "quantity": "2",
    "date_added": "2021-01-29 14:37:24",
    "primary_image": "http://localhost/ecomerce/uploads/1611927444hat.jpg",
    "color": "red"
  },
```

Comment: aggregate by color and group by all other columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 way to do it:

1. If you want to keep your query, you must parse the data first before you parse it to json.

```php
...
function regroup_color($data = array()){
  $ret = array();
  foreach($data as $d){
    $id = $d['id'];
    if(!isset($ret[$id])){
      $color = $d['color'];
      unset($d['color']);
      $ret[$id] = $d;
      $ret[$id]['color'][] = $color;
    }else{
      $ret[$id]['color'][] = $d['color'];
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
$data = regroup_color($data);
echo json_encode($data)
...
```

Or you could just...

2. make the query 2 part, first is for get all `items`, second is for get the `colors` for it

```php
...
$query = "SELECT * FROM items";
// get the data here using query above
$data = {{result of query}};

foreach($data as $i => $d){
  $id = $d['id'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM item_color JOIN colors ON item_color.color_id = colors.id";
  // get the data here using query above
  $colors = {{result of query}};
  foreach($colors as color){
    $data[$i]['color'][] = $color['name'];
  }
}
echo json_encode($data)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**i wanted to add also category so this is what i came with**

```
function regroup_color($data = array(),$data2 = array()){
  // array that will hold our data and we will return it later
$ret = array();
// fetch the data as d
foreach($data as $d){
  //save the id 
  $id = $d['id'];
  //make sure no id was set
  if(!isset($ret[$id])){
    // save the name of the color
    $color = $d['color'];
    unset($d['color']);
    //save all the item data
    $ret[$id] = $d;
    // add color to color array
    $ret[$id]['color'][] = $color;
  }else{
    // if wa alredy did all the above things just keep adding colors to color array
    $ret[$id]['color'][] = $d['color'];
  }
}
  
  
foreach($data2 as $d){

    //save the id 
      $id = $d['id'];
      //make sure no id was set
      if(!isset($ret[$id])){
        // save the name of the color
        $category = $d['category'];
        unset($d['category']);
        $ret[$id] = $d;
        $ret[$id]['category'][] = $category;
      }else{
        $ret[$id]['category'][] = $d['category'];
      }
    }
```

return $ret;
}

**result :**

```
"22": {
"id": "22",
"title": "my products 515151",
"descreption": "5454545455",
"price": "0.05",
"quantity": "2",
"date_added": "2021-01-29 14:37:24",
"primary_image": "http://localhost/ecomerce/uploads/1611927444hat.jpg",
"color": [
  "black",
  "white",
  "pink",
  "red",
  "yellow"
],
"category": [
  "buttom",
  "hats",
  "shoes"
]
```

}